# Unable to get trace ID and span ID in custom logs

Tags: java, kotlin, logging, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

I'm using **implementation("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:3.1.1")** Library to add trace ID and span ID into the Logs. The auto-generated logs do have both but when I try to add custom logs those don't have anything.
Example:

1. Auto-generated logs: **INFO [sample-api,49466c36531753f8,49466c36531753f8]** 46131 ---
   [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       :
   Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2. Custom logs- **INFO [sample-api,,]** 46131 --- [atcher-worker-1] c.l.c.a.w.c.SampleController          :
   1f45520c-8cf4-448a-bf7e-c20bf3401c44 harmeet

As can be seen in the custom logs don’t include trace id and span id

I have tried changing the logging pattern and level as well:

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.web: "info"
    org.hibernate: "error"
  pattern:
    level: "%5p [${spring.application.name:},%X{traceId:-},%X{spanId:-}]"
```

Library used for logging:

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
```

Comment: You need to provide more information on what you're logging and how